# Exiting a nested loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Not sure how to go about doing this but I have the piece of code below and my for loop iterates over each object element in an array and checks a condition in the if statement. If the condition for the if statement is met I want to exit the for loop without continuing to iterate over the rest of the array objects. Is there a way I can structure my loop to do this? (assume all attributes have been initialized)

```
public void remove()
    {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the destination name to be removed: ");
        nameSearch = in.nextLine();
        for(i=0; i < MAX_ELEMENT; i++)
        {
            temp = aDestination[i].getName;
            if(temp == nameSearch)
            {
                aDestination[i]=null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you want to call remove() method multiple times.

Here are the correct modification for you:

```
public void remove()
    {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the destination name to be removed: ");
        nameSearch = in.nextLine();
        for(i=0; i < MAX_ELEMENT; i++)
        {
            // we skip removed destination from previous remove() call
            if(aDestination[i]==null) continue;

            temp = aDestination[i].getName;
            // you need to use equals() to compare String in Java
            if(temp.equals(nameSearch))
            {
                aDestination[i]=null;
                break; // to exit from the loop
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use the `break` keyword, what JAVA provides. Like below:

```
   public void remove() {
          in = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.print("Please enter the destination name to be removed: ");
          nameSearch = in.nextLine();
          for(i=0; i < MAX_ELEMENT; i++) {
                  temp = aDestination[i].getName;
                  if(temp == nameSearch) {
                       aDestination[i]=null;
                       break;
                 }
           }
  }
```

As soon as you condition will be true it will break current running loop. But if you have multiple nested loop and on break you want to come out of some specific loop, you can use Labeled Break.

Although that's not your requirement, but if you want to know about that you can refer below tutorial:

http://www.java-examples.com/java-break-statement-label-example

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Uses the **break** instruction like this:

```
if(temp == nameSearch)
{
     break; // immediatly quit the loop
     aDestination[i]=null;
}
```